# Installation type for PC with single user

Tags: installation, window, setup

Several installation programs ask you to choose if the installed software will be available to:

- all users;
- current user.

What is the best choice for a PC where there will always be only a single user (the administrator)? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the machine only truly has, and will only ever have a single user, the choice is largely irrelevant.

The only time it would matter would be if another user is added to the machine. Anything installed to the other user would need a partial reinstall for the new user.